# Distance/Similarity between two paths in a network

Tags: graph-theory, network, network-flow

I have a weighted directed graph representing the intensity of movements of individuals between locations, with weights representing the mobility flow.

I have another dataset consisting of particular paths that are taken by specific individuals. For example, for a person named Alice, I know how she moved from node A to node B, potentially via some intermediate stops through other nodes. What I want to evaluate is how likely this is given the mobility network (the weighted directed graph). Essentially, can I compute some kind of distance/statistical measure that tells me how "deviant" or how "consistent" these observed paths are, given the mobility network (taking into account the edge weights)?

Comment: There isn't generally any unique set of path flows adding up to the arc flows, nor to the origin-destination flows - even if those paths follow "good behavior" such as not cycling back on a node, but especially if they are not so constrained.

Comment: @mountaincat Thanks for the comment. I am not sure if I understand completely, but let me try to put it differently: for a given observed aggregated mobility flow along a certain path, there is basically an infinite number of possible trajectories that could have contributed to it? I agree with that, but from all the observed mobility flows, is it not possible to at least constrain these sets, or at least quantify the likelihood of certain trajectories? Do I need to construct a model somehow from the observed mobility flows in order to do that?

Comment: As not a graph theorist but a transpo modeler, it appears you want to estimate a path-choice model from path observation samples and aggregate arc traffic flows.  (Apologies if I misunderstand.) You could devise some shortest-path criteria as weighted sums of arc attributes (e.g. time, distance, cost), then vary those weights, and count how many observed paths agree with the modeled shortest paths, to find a best fit.  Advanced path choice methods maximize likelihood. I'm not aware of how to use the arc flows without a orig-dest matrix. (Matrix estimation methods need path choice criteria.)